# How to parse this JSON file in Rust using serde?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I am new to Rust. I am trying to parse a JSON file and store the data as objects in rust.

This is how the JSON File looks:

```
{
"comment": ["some comments"],
"data": [
    ["name", "line 1"],
    ["name", ["line 1", "line 2"]],
    ......
    ["name", "line 1"]
]
//(The line where the error is coming)

}
```

I made structures like this:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct my_data {
    comment: String,
    data: Vec<sub_data>,
}
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct sub_data {
    name: String, 
    pattern: Vec<String>,
}
```

Then I tried this code but got an error:

```
Error("missing field `Comment`", line: 1381, column: 1)',
```

Code:

```
pub fn read_json () {
    let path = "./src/my_file.json";
    let data = fs::read_to_string(path).expect("Unable to read file");
    let obj: my_data = serde_json::from_str(&data).expect("Unable to parse");
    println!("{:?}", obj);
    return
}
```

Can someone help fix this?

Comment: Why do you have `#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]`? None of your example data shows the inputs feilds being written in `PascalCase`. What `rename_all ` does is it tells `serde` that you want it to capitalize the first letter of each word in your variable names when serializing and deserializing. This helpful if your data comes in that format, but you want to keep your field names clean. However, this does not seem to apply to you.

Comment: @Locke ah sorry. I just copied it off somewhere earlier and forgot to remove. I removed it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your JSON is not in PascalCase. That attribute tells serde to look for "Comment" and "Data" instead of the original names. Serde (by default) skips all the other keys and is letting you know it didn't find any called "Comment". The JSON might be camelCase, but since all the keys are single words, I'll just leave it without a rename attribute. You can check out the [container attributes documentation](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html) for yourself to decide.

Second, you aren't representing the JSON arrays properly in your rust types. The arrays that are represented by `SubData` are fine since serde will assume they're the struct members in order, but the array represented by `SubData.pattern` is either an array or a single string, so you can't deserialize it directly to a single type. That's what the untagged enum `StringOrList` is handling. If you want to make this always a `Vec`, you can use [the `deserialize_with` attribute](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#deserialize_with) or the [`serde_with` crate](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/index.html).

```rs
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct MyData {
    comment: Vec<String>,
    data: Vec<SubData>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct SubData {
    name: String, 
    pattern: StringOrList,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum StringOrList {
    String(String),
    List(Vec<String>),
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! About the PascalCase, My bad. I was copying a bunch of code earlier and didn't remove it.

Thanks for pointing out my mistake. Your code is working!